# How to compare two columns in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I want to do this in tcl. But I just started tcl a week before,

I have below array, I want to modify the elements in column2. Check each element in column2, & its first appearance in column1 and the corresponding element in column2 (of the particular row)

```
A   N  B  0      
B   J  P  1    
C   A  U  9
A   B  O  4
W   L  K  0
```

For example, C in column2, row3, is A, and A in column1 it appeared first time in row1 and its corresponding element in column2 is N.

2nd example: The element in column2, row4 is B. B appeared in column1 first time at row2, its corresponding element in column2 is J.

Desired output:

```
A   N  B  0 
B   J  P  1      
C   N  U  9
A   J  O  4
W   L  K  0
```

Comment: Do you have any attempts yet at the problem that you could edit in your question?

Comment: What separates the columns? Does formatting matter?